# Including External JS Problems

Tags: javascript, html, external

I have been looking into JS and have decided to make a 'Pong' game where a ball bounces of two parallel paddles, one controlled by arrow keys and the other controlled by AI. I am using Brackets to compile my code. My problem is that I want to import external functions that I have made so my code looks nice and tidy, but nothing shows up. Here is my main game code and my external functions code:

```
<html>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script>

import {drawRect} from 'useful functions';    

var canvas;
var canvasContext;
var ballX = 0;
var ballY = 300 - ballSize/2;
var ballSize = 10;
var ballSpeedX = 5;

window.onload = function()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var FPS = 60;
    setInterval(function() {
        moveEverything();
        drawEverything();
    }, 1000/FPS);
}

function moveEverything()
{
    ballX = ballX + ballSpeedX;
    if (ballX > (canvas.width - ballSize)) {
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    }
}

function drawEverything()
{
    drawRect(ballY, ballX, ballSize, ballSize, 'red');
}

</script>
</html>
```

And my external functions code:

```
<script>

export function drawRect(x, y, width, height, colour) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle(colour);
    canvasContext.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

</script>
```

By the way, my main code is .html and my extensions are .js

Thank you for reading and happy coding!

Comment: Are you using any transpiler like `babel`?If not the by default most browsers don't support the es6 modules

Comment: @ManosKounelakis sorry I'm quite new to this topic, could you explain deeper, please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Also do you mean that the script tags are saved in a `.js` file? Using script tags inside a `.js` file will cause an error since script tags are only meant to be used in an html document

Comment: @ManosKounelakis yes I do. So, I have deleted them and it is asking for an identifier. Is this an identifier '<!DOCTYPE html>' ?

Comment: Script tags are html tags(they have nothing to do with javascript syntax).

Comment: @ManosKounelakis ik that but is that like the same thing as a javascript identifier? (sorry if you are getting frustrated with my ignorence)

Comment: You don't appear to be importing your external Javascript anywhere in the code you supplied.  try putting `<script src="./external.js"></script>` between the Canvas element, and your html script..  oh, you have use `import` most browsers don't have built in support of module loading, although it's getting there.